# How to reset UIPickerView to index:0,iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipickerview

I am trying to reset the `UIPickerView` on button click.
My pickerview id is created at runtime, I have delegates set already.
After googling, I found

```
[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
```

But this makes my app crash everytime it reaches here.

Object at index 0 is "Select from list" and then the items.
When the submit button is clicked, I want that the "Select from list" should remain at the top of my label (selected index: 0).

Here is my code

```
ViewDidload

 pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;

  -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
        return 1;
    }


 // Total rows in our component.
    -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
        return [nameArray count];
    }

// Display each row's data.
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [nameArray objectAtIndex: row];
    }

// Do something with the selected row.

    -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
        dlbl.hidden=YES;
        NSLog(@"You selected this: %@", [nameArray objectAtIndex: row]);
        [btnSelectDesigner setTitle:[nameArray objectAtIndex: row] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

    }
```

and, on button click:

```
-(IBAction)btnSubmitClicked:(id)sender{
[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Some code would help debug better.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
[picker reloadAllComponents];
[picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Can you explain the point of using reloadAllComponents please ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @AnthoPak not sure why I needed to call that method 6 years ago but it shouldn't be necessary

Comment: Hahaha classic!

Answer (score 9):

Swift version:

`picker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)`

Answer (score 5):

```
//use this line for going at the top of the label index 0:

[picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: On button click?  gives me crash

Comment: Have you allocated your array?? is first time its working fine??..can you show your crash log here.. what is being happen exactly ..